# Why are attributes defined outside __init__ in popular packages like SQLAlchemy or Pydantic?

Tags: python, class, sqlalchemy, attributes, pydantic

I'm modifying an app, trying to use Pydantic for my application models and SQLAlchemy for my database models.

I have existing classes, where I defined attributes inside the `__init__` method as I was taught to do:

```py
class Measure:
    def __init__(
        self,
        t_received: int,
        mac_address: str,
        data: pd.DataFrame,
        battery_V: float = 0
    ):
        self.t_received = t_received
        self.mac_address = mac_address
        self.data = data
        self.battery_V = battery_V
```

In both Pydantic and SQLAlchemy, following the docs, I have to define those attributes outside the `__init__` method, for example in Pydantic:

```py
import pydantic

class Measure(pydantic.BaseModel):
    t_received: int
    mac_address: str
    data: pd.DataFrame
    battery_V: float
```

Why is it the case? Isn't this bad practice? Is there any impact on other methods (classmethods, staticmethods, properties ...) of that class?

Note that this is also *very unhandy* because when I instantiate an object of that class, I don't get suggestions on what parameters are expected by the constructor!

Comment: Pydantic models are not normal classes, they are [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) (see https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/1ac1199f08c42803dc7c5e6fae754afd53e3f1b4/pydantic/main.py#L46). Also your IDE should still be able to autocomplete your initialisers (at least PyCharm does).

Comment: I have PyCharm and when I instantiate it says **kwargs

Comment: @Selcuk No, this requires special extensions. And no, Pydantic models are not dataclasses. [Dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) are dataclasses. Pydantic models want to be _treated_ like dataclasses by static type checkers, which has recently been made possible via `@dataclass_transform`. There is a plugin for PyCharm that allows proper auto-suggestions for the `__init__` method.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I stand corrected. I just checked and yes, I seem to have installed the [Pydantic plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12861-pydantic) and then forgotten about it. Dataclasses are supported out-of-the-box, though.

Comment: @Selcuk You're right, `dataclasses` are, in the sense that you don't need to install a plugin. Under the hood their type support is still a hack (not in a bad way) because they require special treatment. See my answer for the link to the `mypy` plugin module as an example. But for most people this probably doesn't matter.

Comment: SQLAlchemy predates the Python's typing features by many years.  Typing support is being added, but it is still a work in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining attributes of a class in the class namespace directly is totally acceptable and is not special per se for the packages you mentioned. Since the class namespace is (among other things) essentially a blueprint for instances of that class, defining attributes there can actually be useful, when you want to e.g. provide all public attributes with type annotations in a single place in a consistent manner.

Consider also that a public attribute does not necessarily need to be reflected by a parameter in the constructor of the class. For example, this is entirely reasonable:

```py
class Foo:
    a: list[int]
    b: str

    def __init__(self, b: str) -> None:
        self.a = []
        self.b = b
```

In other words, just because something is a public attribute, that does not mean it should have to be provided by the user upon initialization. To say nothing of protected/private attributes.

What is special about Pydantic (to take your example), is that the metaclass of `BaseModel` as well as the class itself does a whole lot of magic with the attributes defined in the class namespace. Pydantic refers to a model's typical attributes as "fields" and one bit of magic allows special checks to be done during initialization based on those fields you defined in the class namespace. For example, the constructor must receive keyword arguments that correspond to the non-optional fields you defined.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    field_a: str
    field_b: int = 1


obj = MyModel(
    field_a="spam",  # required
    field_b=2,       # optional
    field_c=3.14,    # unexpected/ignored
)
```

If I were to omit `field_a` during construction of a `MyModel` instance, an error would be raised. Likewise, if I had tried to pass `field_b="eggs"`, an error would be raised.

So the fact that you don't write your own `__init__` method is a **feature** Pydantic provides you. You only define the fields and an appropriate constructor is "magically" there for you already.

As for the drawback you mentioned, where you don't get any auto-suggestions, that is true by default for all IDEs. Static type checkers cannot understand that dynamic constructor and simply infer what arguments are expected. Currently this is solved via extensions, such as the [`mypy` plugin](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/mypy_plugin/) and the [PyCharm plugin](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/pycharm_plugin/). Maybe soon the `@dataclass_transform` decorator from [PEP 681](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/)
will standardize this for similar packages and thus improve support by static type checkers.

It is also worth noting that even the standard library's [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) only work via [special extensions](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/plugins/dataclasses.py) in type checkers.

To your other question, there is obviously some impact on methods of such classes (by design), though the specifics are not always obvious. You should of course not simply write your own `__init__` method without being careful to call the superclass' `__init__` properly inside it. Also, `@property`-setters currently [don't work as you would expect it](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/1577) (though it is debatable if it even makes sense to use properties on Pydantic models).

To wrap up, this approach is not only **not** bad practice, it is a great idea to reduce boilerplate code and it is extremely common these days, as evidenced by the fact that hugely popular and established packages (like the aforementioned Pydantic, as well as e.g. SQLAlchemy, Django and others) use this pattern to a certain extent.

Answer (score 0):

Pydantic has its own (rewriting) magic, but SQLalchemy is a bit easier to explain.

A SA model looks like this :

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
>>> class User(Base):
...
...     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
...     name = Column(String)
```

Column, Integer and String are `descriptors`. A descriptor is a class that overrides the get and set methods. In practice, this means the class can control how data is accessed and stored.

For example this assignment would now use the `__set__` method from Column:

```
class User(Base):
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = Column(String)

user = User()
user.name = 'John'
```

This is the same as `user.name.__set__('John')` , however, because of the MRO, it finds a set method in `Column`, so uses that instead. In a simplified version the Column looks something like this:

```
class Column:
    def __init__(self, field=""):
        self.field= field
    def __get__(self, obj, type):
        return obj.__dict__.get(self.field)
    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        if validate_field(val)
           obj.__dict__[self.field] = val
        else:
           print('not a valid value')
```

(This is similar to using @property. A Descriptor is a re-usable @property)